# Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data, : object is not a matrix, for beta regression model

Tags: r

I am trying to use beta regression model by the function `betareg()`

```
df_lm <- betareg(hist ~ `FP-BLURAZ` + `FP-TIGBLO` + `FP-GREAPP`,
                 data = T1,
                 na.action = "na.omit")
```

but it shows the error message “object is not a matrix”

hist is the proportion of Hispanic people in a zip code, and I make sure the number is between 0 and 1 (not including 0 or 1). Other independent variable are also proportions between 0 and 1.
The weird thing is that I run the same code for other race like

```
df_lm <- betareg(white ~ `FP-BLURAZ` + `FP-TIGBLO` + `FP-GREAPP`,
                 data = T1,
                 na.action = "na.omit")
```

in the same data set, `T1`, and works fine, only the histogram has problem (I calculate each race proportion in the exactly same way, so these number should have the same format)

I could provide any additional information if needed.

This is head(T1), obviously wh generally has higher percentage, but I guess that shouldn’t be the issue of the error?

(I cannot embeds an image, so this is the link for the data screenshot)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O03I.png

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Hi Yong Nan Chang, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you can include `T1` or a dummy dataset that resembles it, and `library("whatever.package.includes.betareg"),  we could probably help out more.

Comment: So you named a column in `T1`, *hist* that corresponds to *hispanic* proportion? Given the *white* column, are you sure it is not *his**p***? Please post output of `dput(T1)`. If too large, post `head`, `dput(head(T1))`, so we can reproduce.

Comment: @Michael the library is “betareg”, but I try the same thing for logistic regression by glm() function also returns the same error

Comment: @Parfait Thanks, I have include the my dataset in the original post, hopes that will be more clear

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of sample data. See [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451). But looking at image, it is a typo. It should be `hisp` (not `hist`). But then `white` should be `wh`. Please post actual, runnable code with `dput` of data.